# Check if repeated row has value in one attribute in any of the rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID  | Position
--------------
 1  |    0
 1  |    3
 1  |    5
 2  |    1
 2  |    2
 3  |    1
 3  |    5
```

I would like to extract for each ID if it contains a specific value.

In this case, if that value is 5 I would need a table like this:

```
ID  | HasNumber
---------------
 1  |  true
 2  |  false
 3  |  true
```

Any solutions or hints about how could I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use group by and conditional counting:

```
select id, count(*) filter (where position = 5) > 0 as has_number
from the_table
group by id;
```

Another option is to use the `bool_or()` aggregate:

```
select id, bool_or(position = 5) as has_number
from the_table
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

use conditional aggregation

```
select id,
MAX(CASE WHEN position = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as HasNumber
from table_name t1 group by id
```

Comment: You really don't need the sub query. Just do `MAX(CASE WHEN value = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`